# Generating a Line Chart using D3 with Next.js with data pulled from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I've been trying to generate a D3.js chart to appear on my webpage that just maps the average pace of a run to the date the run was done at. The error I keep running in to is: `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,450LNaN,0".` Below is the relevant code:

```
const RunGraph = ({ data }) => {
  const svgRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const chartData = data.map(item => ({
      date: item.date,
      avgPace: item.avgPace,
    }))

    const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 }
    const width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right
    const height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom

    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current)

    //Maps a continuous time domain to a continuous output range, such as mapping a date value to a position along a time axis
    const x = d3.scaleTime()
      //Returns an array of evenly spaced numbers from the first element array to the last element in the array minus 1 (Basically just for generating tick marks on a graph)
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(d3.extent(chartData, d => d.date))
      .nice()

    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0])
      .nice()

    const values = Object.keys(chartData[0]).filter(key => key !== "date");

    y.domain([
      d3.min(chartData, d => d3.min(values, value => d[value])),
      d3.max(chartData, d => d3.max(values, value => d[value]))
    ])

    const line = d3.line()
      .x(d => x(d.date))
      .y(d => y(d.avgPace))

    const paths = values?.map(value => {
      return {
        value: value,
        path: svg
          .append('path')
          .datum(chartData)
          .attr('fill', 'none')
          .attr('stroke', 'steelBlue')
          .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
          .attr('d', line.y(d => y(d[value])))
      }
    })

    svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

    svg.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(y))

  }, [data])

  
  return (
    <svg ref={svgRef}>

    </svg>
  )
}

export default RunGraph
```

After doing some digging, it looks like it could be the way that `avgPace` is being read in to `const paths` is what is causing the issue, specifically this line: `.attr('d', line.y(d => y(d[value])))` however, just to see what type `avgPace` is, I console logged `console.log(typeof chartData[0].avgPace)` and it logged it as a number, so I'm not sure what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely the fact that your `date`s come from your database as strings, that is, they are neither timestamps, nor JS `Date` instances. I got a similar error to yours when trying your code with string dates, then I added date parsing

```js
chartData.forEach(o=>{o.date = new Date(o.date)});
```

and it works (inventing some data, adding standard [margins code](https://observablehq.com/@d3/margin-convention), reducing the size, and excluding the react stuff, all to be able to add your code in a SO snippet):

```js
const chartData = [
    {date: '2023-05-10T02:21:12.788Z', avgPace: 10},
    {date: '2023-05-10T02:32:12.788Z', avgPace: 15},
    {date: '2023-05-10T02:43:12.788Z', avgPace: 8},
    {date: '2023-05-10T02:54:12.788Z', avgPace: 12}
];
chartData.forEach(o=>{o.date = new Date(o.date)});
const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 }
const width = 360;// - margin.left - margin.right
const height = 240;// - margin.top - margin.bottom

//const svg = select(svgRef.current)
const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("x",100)


//Maps a continuous time domain to a continuous output range, such as mapping a date value to a position along a time axis
const x = d3.scaleTime()
    //Returns an array of evenly spaced numbers from the first element array to the last element in the array minus 1 (Basically just for generating tick marks on a graph)
    .range([margin.left, width-margin.right])
    .domain(d3.extent(chartData, d => d.date))
    .nice()

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height-margin.bottom, margin.top])
    .nice()

const values = Object.keys(chartData[0]).filter(key => key !== "date");

y.domain([
    d3.min(chartData, d => d3.min(values, value => d[value])),
    d3.max(chartData, d => d3.max(values, value => d[value]))
])

const line = d3.line()
    .x(d => x(d.date))
    .y(d => y(d.avgPace))

const paths = values?.map(value => {
    return {
        value: value,
        path: svg
            .append('path')
            .datum(chartData)
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke', 'steelBlue')
            .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
            .attr('d', line.y(d => y(d[value])))
    }
})

svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height-margin.bottom})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, 0)`)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

`new Date(o.date)` transforms the date strings to `Date` instances; one may also parse them to timestamps using `o.date = Date.parse(o.date)`.

In both cases, one has to take into consideration **time zone issues**. In the data I invented, the times are in the interval 2-3 AM, GMT times (note the 'Z' at the end). However, everyone will see on the x axis the values in their own time zone.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot more sense in regards to what my issue might have been, as I didn't understand how a number could be causing the error. So rather than `avgPace` causing the issue, it was because the data was not formatted correctly when being read in. I will try this later and let you know of the results!